# Rails subtract datepicker dates

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I switched from `date_select` to jQuery UI Datepicker and when I am trying to subtract the dates to get the number of days between those days I am getting the following error.

[image]

The date format for date_select is year/month/day however the format for the jQuery Datepicker is month/day/year. How can I combat this issue and still use Datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
Date.strptime(@pdform.date_finish, "%m/%d/%Y") - Date.strptime(@pdform.date_start, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

For my tests on console, this should work. Hope this helps, good luck!

Edit:
That works for the different date format, but the error shown is about nil classes, so maybe there's something wrong with your values... should check that first!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a null check before the subract operation. something like

`if @pdform.date_finish.present && @pdform.done_start.present &&` //your opertaion

It clearly states you have a nil error